# sharepoint 2013 file don't edit in app

Tags: 2013, file, sharepoint-farm

I have a problem with File in SharePoint 2013.

I can open a file, but I am not able edit it.

This problem is across the SharePoint farm.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fzQA.jpg)

[image]

Comment: which device are you opening it from?

Comment: word, excel. All type of file don't edit

Comment: Do you have edit permissions on the library?

Comment: Yes, I have full permission on a farm and I have permissions on the library.
I think, problems this farm and setting. But I don't know., What is it

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the screen when you open a document?

Comment: I added screenshot. I open the library and click the file. next file open in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Open the document library in explorer using "Open in explorer" button (by browsing site in IE). And then open the document and edit it.

To open document in edit mode directly from library, you will need office web apps.
[This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/webappsserver/configure-office-web-apps-for-sharepoint-2013) article might help you setting up office web apps for SharePoint 2013.

Comment: This method works, but that would be nice if users open a document in Sharepoint library.